# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC in my project, I define the details in `web.xml` like this :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml,
            classpath*:/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I also define a external properties file, I want use the details in the properties file, so I define a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in `applicationContext.xml` like this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/system.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

but when i run my project, I find that I can't use the properties file details in `applicationContext-mvc.xml` ， when I also put the

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/system.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

in my `applicationContext-mvc.xml`, it works well。 That is say I must define `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`  bean in all Spring configuration xml file， it is right？

I do not understand， the `ContextLoaderListener` create the root web application context， the `DispatcherServlet` create the servlet-specifical web application context，

the hierarchy in Spring MVC like this：

[image]

it didn't say that I could use the bean extends from root web application context in Spring MVC configuration file?

I don't know why, whether I must define `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in all Spring configuration file?

Comment: The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` those operate only on the ApplicationContext they are defined in not on parent nor on child contexts. Each context needs to have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Each context isn't the same as each xml file!

Comment: M. Deinum, but why define another configuration file application-hibernate.xml, I also didn't defnid PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean in this file, I can use ${variable}, why?

Comment: As mentioned `ApplicationContext` isn't a single xml file (as I mentioned in my initial comment). `ContextLoaderListener` creates an `ApplicationContext` based on all xml files, the same for `DispatcherServlet`.