# How can I create a new shared folder in Tomcat 8 and load my properties file from that

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a `Spring MVC` web application. I am now trying to externalize all the properties to keep it independent of the war file. I am trying to load some properties from my `application.properties` file. Also I want to load my database credentials also like this. Is there any way I can do this?

I have in my `root-contxt.xml` file,

I tried the following:
[Adding a property file in the shared folder in tomcat 8 and using it in a Spring MVC web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222164/adding-a-property-file-in-the-shared-folder-in-tomcat-8-and-using-it-in-a-spring)

But I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring MVC to externalize properties file.

Please seethe post below which explains it in detail:

[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182183/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-spring-mvc)

Please see below post as well which explains it with example:

[Spring application context external properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270290/spring-application-context-external-properties)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am trying to add the properties in the tomcat shared folder.